# React state hooks work on development but not on build (production)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, google-cloud-platform

I developed a bug tracker app using MERN, and on local, the interface updates in real time when the user performs CRUD operations using react hooks (state) and react context.

But once I deployed my app on google cloud, it seemed to turn into a static website, and if I add,edit, or delete, I have to refresh the page to see the change.

What could be causing this to happen?

Here is my server.js code:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const ticketRoutes = express.Router();
const PORT = 8080;

var path = require("path");
let Ticket = require("./ticket.model");

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (error) => {
  console.log(error);
});


const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once("open", function () {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});

ticketRoutes.route("/").get(function (req, res) {
  Ticket.find(function (err, tickets) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.json(tickets);
    }
  });
});

ticketRoutes.route("/:id").get(function (req, res) {
  let id = req.params.id;
  Ticket.findById(id, function (err, ticket) {
    res.json(ticket);
  });
});

ticketRoutes.route("/add").post(function (req, res) {
  let ticket = new Ticket(req.body);
  ticket
    .save()
    .then((ticket) => {
      res.status(200).json({ ticket });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(400).send("adding new ticket failed");
    });
});

ticketRoutes.route("/delete/:id").delete(function (req, res) {
  Ticket.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function (err, ticket) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send({ ticket });
    }
    return res.status(200).send({ ticket });
  });
});

ticketRoutes.route("/update/:id").post(function (req, res) {
  Ticket.findById(req.params.id, function (err, ticket) {
    if (!ticket) res.status(404).send("data is not found");
    else ticket.ticket_name = req.body.ticket_name;
    ticket.ticket_status = req.body.ticket_status;

    ticket
      .save()
      .then((ticket) => {
        res.json({ ticket });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.status(400).send("Update not possible");
      });
  });
});

app.use("/tickets", ticketRoutes);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "frontend/build")));
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "frontend/build/index.html"));
});

app.listen(process.env.port || 8080, () => {
  console.log("Express app is running on port 8080");
});
```

Comment: We need some more information: How and where is this server deployed? How is the React application also deployed? Do you have an example of how you are accessing the application? How does the react application talk to this server? Any errors in browser console log?

Answer (score 0):

The fix was very in depth, but basically my method of deployment to google cloud was a method that would only work with static web pages. I ended up deploying the app with heroku using this great guide: [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71wSzpLyW9k&list=PLillGF-RfqbbiTGgA77tGO426V3hRF9iE&index=8)